# Extracting the value of variables from objects?

Tags: java, object

I am working on a Java programming assignment, where objects have just been introduced to the class.
I need to write a method that accepts an object of type Money, that has attributes of dollars and cents. It needs to extract the dollars and cents so that they can be added to another object of type Money.

Would I be correct to say that I need to write a support method whose purpose is to extract the dollars and cents variables from the Money object?

I'm thinking that perhaps I need to convert the Money object to a String so that I can extract and manipulate the dollars and cents. Would this be correct?

I'm really confused as to how to approach this. Also I don't want anyone just giving me the answer, as I wont learn anything.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT:
I have been given the following class:

```
package project6;    // Test program for the Money class
public class Project6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    test setMoney and toString
    testSet ();
    testAdd ();
    testSubtract();
    testEquals();
    testLessThan();
}

private static void testSet () {

    System.out.println ("Testing set and toString");
    Money myMoney = new Money();
    myMoney.setMoney(5, 75);
    System.out.println (myMoney.toString());  // $5.75

    myMoney.setMoney(75, 5);
    System.out.println (myMoney.toString()); // $75.05

    myMoney.setMoney(0, 5);
    System.out.println (myMoney.toString()); // $0.05

    myMoney.setMoney (-1, 5); 
    System.out.println (myMoney.toString()); // $0.00

    myMoney.setMoney (1, -5); 
    System.out.println (myMoney.toString()); // $0.00
}

private static void testAdd () {

    System.out.println ("Testing add");
    Money total = new Money();
    Money temp = new Money();
    total.setMoney (0, 0);

    for (int value = 1; value < 100; value += 15) {
        temp.setMoney (1, value);
        System.out.print(total + " + " + temp + " = ");
        total.add(temp);
        System.out.println (total.toString());      
    }
}

private static void testSubtract () {

    System.out.println ("Testing subtract");
    Money total = new Money();
    Money temp = new Money();
    total.setMoney (10, 10);

    for (int value = 1; value < 100; value += 15) {
        temp.setMoney (1, value);
        System.out.print(total + " - " + temp + " = ");
        total.subtract(temp);
        System.out.println (total.toString());      
    }
}

private static void testEquals () {

    System.out.println ("Testing equals");
    Money wallet1 = new Money();
    Money wallet2 = new Money();

    wallet1.setMoney(7, 7);
    wallet2.setMoney(7, 7);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " = " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.equals(wallet2));
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " = " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet2.equals(wallet1));
    wallet2.setMoney(7, 17);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " = " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.equals(wallet2));
    wallet2.setMoney(17, 1);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " = " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.equals(wallet2));

}

private static void testLessThan () {

    System.out.println ("Testing lessThan");
    Money wallet1 = new Money();
    Money wallet2 = new Money();

    wallet1.setMoney(7, 7);
    wallet2.setMoney(7, 7);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " < " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.lessThan(wallet2));
    wallet2.setMoney(17, 7);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " < " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.lessThan(wallet2));
    wallet2.setMoney(5, 7);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " < " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.lessThan(wallet2));
    wallet2.setMoney(7, 20);
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " < " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.lessThan(wallet2));
    wallet2.setMoney(7, 4);     
    System.out.println (wallet1 + " < " + wallet2 + " is " + 
            wallet1.lessThan(wallet2));
}
}

/*
 * Expected output
 * 
Testing set and toString
$5.75
$75.05
$0.05
$0.00
$0.00
*/
```

I need to write the Money class, with the following instance methods:

1. setMoney(int dollarsIn, int centsIn) –Set the dollars and cents to the values of the parameters.  If either input is negative, set the dollars and cents to 0.
2. add(Money moneyIn) – add the dollars and cents of the parameter to the current object.  If the cents exceeds 100, adjust the dollars and cents accordingly.
3. subtract(Money moneyIn) – subtract the parameter from the current object If the cents fall below 0, then the dollars and cents must be adjusted. If the number of  dollars falls below 0, then set both the dollars and cents to 0
4. boolean equals(Money moneyIn): return true if both the dollars and cents of the parameter match the dollars and cents of the current object, otherwise return false
5. boolean lessThan(Money moneyIn): return true if the current object represents less money than the parameter. otherwise return false
6. String toString(): return the values of the object as a String formatted as $dd.cc

I figured I would start with the setMoney and toString methods and see whether I can instantiate a Money object and return the objects attributes. So in my Project6 class I have commented out all of the methods except for the setMoney() and toString() methods.
Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
package project6;


public class Money {
    private int dollars;
    private int cents;

public void setMoney(int dollarsIn, int centsIn){
    dollars = dollarsIn;
    cents = centsIn;
}

public int getDollars(){
    return dollars;
}

public int getCents(){
    return cents;
}

public void add(Money moneyIn){
    dollars = dollars + moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = cents + moneyIn.getCents();
    dollars = dollars + (cents - (cents%100))/100;  // roll over cents into dollars if greater than 100   
}

public String toString(Money moneyIn){
    return "$" + moneyIn.getDollars() + "." + moneyIn.getCents();
}

}
```

When I just try to run the testSet() method from the Project6 class, I get the following output:

```
Testing set and toString
project6.Money@7885a30c
project6.Money@7885a30c
project6.Money@7885a30c
project6.Money@7885a30c
project6.Money@7885a30c
```

instead of the following expected output:

```
Testing set and toString
$5.75
$75.05
$0.05
$0.00
$0.00
```

---

EDIT2 - So in the setMoney() method call, I need to return the money object? This perhaps could explain my unexpected output?

EDIT 3 - ok, I have advanced a bit, I am successfully setting and getting dollars and cents.
I modified the Project6 class to confirm that I am correctly setting and getting the dollars and cents variables, like so:

```
System.out.println ("Testing set and toString");
    Money myMoney = new Money();
    myMoney.setMoney(5, 75);
            System.out.println("Dollars = " + myMoney.getDollars());
            System.out.println("Cents = " + myMoney.getCents());
```

Now when I run the program it outputs

```
Dollars = 5
Cents = 75
```

According to the instructions I have been given, I need to write a method called toString(), however such a method is native in Java (from what I have worked out).
So I think I have to pass a String to the toString() method which I have preformatted to $dd.cc

EDIT 4 - The toString() method when called is in the following format:

```
myMoney.setMoney (1, -5);
System.out.println (myMoney.toString()); // $0.00
```

I think I just figured it out! I don't pass the object as a parameter! I simply call the getDollars() and getCents() methods!
I had previously thought that I could only call those methods with respect an object, but it seems that is done during the method call!
Yay! Happy dance!!

EDIT 6:

When I call the following method from the Project6 class:

```
private static void testAdd () {

    System.out.println ("Testing add");
    Money total = new Money();
    Money temp = new Money();
    total.setMoney (0, 0);

    for (int value = 1; value < 100; value += 15) {
        temp.setMoney (1, value);
                    System.out.println("TOTAL = " + total);
                    System.out.println("TEMP = " + temp);
        System.out.print(total + " + " + temp + " = ");
        total.add(temp);
        System.out.println (total.toString());      
    }
}
```

It enters the for loop and prints out the values of total and temp, then adds them.
The second time through the loop, it prints the value of total, but not temp, and does not add them.
For all subsequent iterations through the loop it does not print the values of either total or temp.
I have been stepping through it line by line with the debugger, but I am totally stumped as to why this is happening.
Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what I am missing/doing wrong?
Here is my current code for the Money class:

```
package project6;


public class Money {
    private int dollars;
    private int cents;

public Money(){
}

public void setMoney(int dollarsIn, int centsIn){
    dollars = dollarsIn;
    cents = centsIn;
    if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0){
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }
}

private int getDollars(){
    return dollars;
}

private int getCents(){
    return cents;   
}

public void add(Money moneyIn){
    dollars = dollars + moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = cents + moneyIn.getCents();

    if (cents >= 100){
        dollars = dollars + (cents - (cents%100))/100;  // roll over cents into dollars if greater than 100   
        cents = (cents%100);
        moneyIn.setMoney(dollars, cents);
    }
}

public void subtract(Money moneyIn){
    dollars = dollars - moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = cents - moneyIn.getCents();

    if (cents < 0){
        dollars = dollars + (cents + (cents%100)) / 100;
        cents = 100 + cents;    
    }
    if (dollars < 0){
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }
}

public boolean equals(Money moneyIn){ 
    dollars = moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = moneyIn.getCents();
    Money newMoney = new Money();
    return (moneyIn.equals(newMoney));
}

public String toString(){ 
    String output = "";
    dollars = getDollars();
    cents = getCents();
    if (cents < 10)
        output = "$" + dollars + ".0" + cents;
    return output;
   }

}
```

Comment: Show what you have so far and we can tell you what's wrong

Comment: Yes, show what you've achieved so far.. that'll be the best way to learn.

Comment: ...and you should post your Money class

Comment: Why not just create a simple copy constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have to add a few basic methods to your `Money` class.

This is how I would do it:

- The `Money` constructor accepts two arguments, one for dollars and one for cents
- The dollars and cents would be properties of the class (no need to put the value in a `String` and have to work with it)
- Add getters and setters for the dollars and cents
- Override the equals() method to compare with other `Money` objects by dolars/cents
- Implement an `add(Money)` method in which you pass another `Money` object and add its value (dollars/cents) to the current object

**Edited:**
To handle cases where the constructor receives more than 100 cents, we would do:

```
this.cents = cents%100;
this.dollars = dollars + ((cents-this.cents) / 100);
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: How do we handle when a user instantiates a Money object with >100 cents?

Comment: You could do something like `this.cents = cents%100;` and `this.dollars = dollars-this.cents;`

Comment: I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to implement the getters for a Money object.

Comment: All `Money` properties should be private and the only way to get their value from the outside is to use a getter provided by the class. In the `getDollars()` and `getCents()` methods, you only have to `return` the corresponding properties of each method.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking that perhaps I need to convert the Money object to a String so that I can extract and manipulate the dollars and cents. Would this be correct?

This seems too complicated of a solution for something simple, your other idea seems better. You probably want to do something with "getter" and "setter" methods. I'm sure you've learned about those, if not they are methods meant to get and set the private fields of an object.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two getter function on money class for dollar and cents...
In your present class use these method as per your requirements.
Last thing you can override toString() in money class for debugging and printing for information..
I hope this might help you

Comment: How do I override toString() ? I have managed to sort the getter and setter methods and print them to the screen but am stuck on formatting for toString()

Comment: Try this example... Here to override toString means to print member variable data.   http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

Comment: Would that work when in the Project6.java file the call is 
System.out.println (myMoney.toString());

In the example you posted the call is
System.out.println(monsterTruck);

I only ask, because the Project6.java file is given to us and we must write the Money.java file.

Comment: Also it appears when using the @Override, I cannot pass an object to the toString() method. Since I need to print the formatted Money object, wouldn't I need to pass it to the toString() method?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking that perhaps I need to convert the Money object to a String so that I can extract and manipulate the dollars and cents. Would this be correct?

You do not need conversion to `String`. *Adding* is a behaviour which belongs to  `Money` itself. You could write a method `add(Money m)`, which adds the amounts and gives you a new `Money`-Object with the result back.

```
public Money add(Money m){
    //Do the adding here
}
```

Comment: That's where I am stuck, I am unsure how to access the dollar and cents amounts from a Money object.

Comment: I'm making some progress. I have completed the add() and subtract() methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like this provided dollars and cents are the variables of the money class

```
 public Money addToNewMoney(Money money) {
        Money newMoney = new Money();

    newMoney.setDollars(money.getDollars());
    newMoney.setDollars(money.getCents());

return newMoney;
}
```

Later perform other operations using new Money object.

May be this will Help

Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't do anything; the  scope of the new object is local to the method and this method has no return type. Your addition is lost at the end of the method.

Comment: @EvanBechtol, I have modified the code based on your words.

Comment: How are you passing an argument to getDollars for 'newMoney', but using the same method for 'money' and passing no arguments?  I think it should be like this... newMoney.setDollars(money.getDollars());     Do the same thing for cents, then return newMoney.

Comment: @EvanBechtol,sorry typo mistake.forgive me

Answer (score 0):

To expand in the previous answer, in Java a class usually has its fields defined as private objects with public getter and setter methods for each field.

In your case the money object most likely has the methods getDollars() and getCents()

So your method takes a money object as its parameter

```
public double addMoney(Money obj) {
    ....
}
```

Inside the method you can simply call the getter methods for dollars and cents to get their values

```
public double addMoney(Money obj) {
    int dollars = obj.getDollars();
    double cents = obj.getCents();
    ....
}
```

If you have a running count of the money in your class with getter and setter methods it would look like this

```
public double addMoney(Money obj) {
    int dollars = obj.getDollars();
    double cents = obj.getCents();
    this.setTotalDollars(this.getTotalDollars() + dollars);
    this.setTotalCents(this.getTotalCents() + cents);
    return this.getTotalDollars() + this.getTotalCents();
}
```

To add to another object just use the getDollars() and getCents() method on each and add them together

Strings should not be used anywhere unless that is the required return type

Answer (score 0):

Okay, pay close attention to this, the logic for your setMoney Method is wrong to get the expected output, your method has to look like this.

```
      public void setMoney (int dollarsln, int centsln){

          if( centsln > 0 && dollarsln > 0 || centsln >= 0 && dollarsln >= 0){
          dollars = dollarsln;
             cents = centsln;
          }
          else{
             dollars = 0;
             cents = 0;
          } 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem!
In my toString() method I had set up an output string for when the cents < 10, but I failed to put in a case for when they were >=10.

Fixed that & now it works as expected!

This has been an excellent learning experience, thank you all for helping me, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As I received quality pointers from multiple people here, I think it is difficult to credit a single person with helping me solve this problem.
What is the protocol for such a situation?

The final code I successfully used for this was:

```
/*
 * This Money class is for use with Project6 class.
 * It provides public methods as follows:
 * setMoney(int dollarsIn, centsIn)     sets a Money objects attributes
 * add(Money moneyIn)                   adds the dollars & cents of the parameter to the current object
 * subtract(Money moneyIn)              subtracts the parameter from the current object
 * boolean equals(Money moneyIn)        returns true if both dollars and cents of the parameter matches those of the current object, otherwise false 
 * boolean lessThan(Money moneyIn)      return true if the current object represents less money than the parameter, otherwise false
 * String toString()                    returns the values of the object formatted as $dd.cc
 * 
 * It provides private methods as follows:
 * int getDollars()                     returns dollar value of the current object
 * int getCents()                        returns cents value of the current object
 *
 */
package project6;
/**
 *  @author Ross Satchell
 *  @version 1.0
 */ 
public class Money {
    private int dollars;    /** variable to hold dollar value of object*/
    private int cents;      /** variable to hold cents value of object*/

    public Money(){         /** constructor for object of type Money */
}

/** Set the  Money object's attributes. If dollarsIn or centsIn are
 *  less than zero, it sets both dollars and cents to zero
 * @param dollarsIn
 * @param centsIn
 */    
public void setMoney(int dollarsIn, int centsIn){
    dollars = dollarsIn;
    cents = centsIn;
    if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0){
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }
}

/** Gets dollar attribute from Money object
 * @return dollars
 */
private int getDollars(){
    return dollars;
}

/** Gets cents attribute from object of type Money
 * @return cents
 */
private int getCents(){
    return cents;   
}

/** 
 * Adds two Money objects together
 * @param moneyIn 
 */
public void add(Money moneyIn){
    dollars = this.getDollars() + moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = this.getCents() + moneyIn.getCents();

    if (cents >= 100){
        dollars = dollars + (cents - (cents%100))/100;  // roll over cents into dollars if greater than 100   
        cents = (cents%100);
        this.setMoney(dollars, cents);
    }
}

/**
 * Subtracts a Money object from another Money object.
 * If result is less than zero, this method sets both 
 * dollars and cents to zero
 *  
 * @param moneyIn 
 */
public void subtract(Money moneyIn){
    dollars = dollars - moneyIn.getDollars();
    cents = cents - moneyIn.getCents();

    if (cents < 0){                     // roll over cents if less than zero
        dollars -= (cents/100) + 1;
        cents = 100 + cents;    
    }
    if (dollars < 0){                   
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Determines whether 2 money objects attributes are equal
 * @param moneyIn
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean equals(Money moneyIn){    
    return (this.getCents() == moneyIn.getCents() && this.getDollars() == moneyIn.getDollars()); 
}

/**
 * Determines whether the monetary attributes of an Money object are less than those of another Money object
 * @param moneyIn
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean lessThan(Money moneyIn){  
    return (this.getDollars() * 100 + this.getCents()) < (moneyIn.getDollars() * 100 + moneyIn.getCents());    
}

/**
 * Converts Money objects attributes to a String 
 * @return String
 */
public String toString(){ 
    String output;
    if (getCents() < 10)
        output = "$" + this.getDollars() + ".0" + this.getCents();
    else output = "$" + this.getDollars() + "." + this.getCents();
    return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package test;

public class BankAccount
{
    private Money balance;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        // start with zero balance
        balance = new Money(0,0);
    }

    public void addMoneyToBalance(Money m)
    {
        balance.setDollars(m.getDollars());
        balance.setCents(m.getCents());
    }

    public String accountBalanceToString()
    {
        return "$" + balance.getDollars() + "." + balance.getCents();
    }

    // inner class defines how money is held in memory
    private static class Money
    {
        private int dollars;
        private int cents;

        public Money()
        {}

        // overloaded constructor, for a one-shot setup
        public Money(int newDollars, int newCents)
        {
            dollars = newDollars;
            cents = newCents;
        }

        public void setDollars(int newDollars)
        {
            dollars = newDollars;
        }

        public void setCents(int newCents)
        {
            cents = newCents;
        }

        public int getDollars()
        {
            return dollars;
        }

        public int getCents()
        {
            return cents;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount();
        // prepare a deposit of $69.69
        Money currentDeposit = new Money(69, 69);
        myAccount.addMoneyToBalance(currentDeposit);
        System.out.println(myAccount.accountBalanceToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Also I don't want anyone just giving me the answer, as I wont learn anything." I learn from observing similar examples and tweaking them to fit my needs - it works for me, and is a great skill to learn for reading tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very useful. I now understand your point of learning from observation.

Part of my assignment is to use a toString() method, which seems to be a native method in Java. Can you advise how to use it, I had tried returning a string that contains "$" + dollars + "." + cents.

However it returns something like the following

project6.Money@15b57dcb

What have I missed?

Comment: It sounds like your toString() method may be returning type Money, or perhaps you have not defined a toString() and are using the default? Please post your toString() method for further investigation. My comment was not about your learning style, rather that learning by example is the standard for tutorials on the web today. If my answer led to your success, please upvote and select it as the accepted answer.